# Where can I get Papyri 75 images?

Tags: bible, new-testament, manuscript

It seems that it is [not available anymore from this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120218120828/http://chrles.multiply.com/photos/album/53/Bible_Papyrus_p75#)
Any secondary copy would be appreciated.

UPD I need all leaves (~100 in good quality to be able to read), not one sample scattered over the internet.

Comment: See [this](http://legacy.earlham.edu/~seidti/iam/tc_pap75.html), [this](http://www.islamic-awareness.org/Bible/Text/Mss/) and [this](http://rapgenius.com/Flame-scripture-alone-lyrics#note-1601672).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping.

Comment: @Flimzy I think the asker is interested in finding images for the manuscripts.

Comment: @Anonymous: That's still off topic.

Comment: @UlrikheLukoie I think you should be informed that [we are not Christians](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians).

Comment: @UlrikheLukoie [Is this what you are looking for?](http://www.csntm.org/manuscript/zoomify/GA_P75?page=4#viewer)

Comment: @jayyeshu thanx mate, this is it!